# Java swing Frame height is too big

Tags: java, swing, jframe

The main frame of my application has a lot of vertical content, so I put it in a ScrollPane. If there is too much content for the screen to fit in, the ScrollPane does its thing and I can
scroll.
However, the frame height then is always 20 pixels larger than the screen height, which is really annoying.

MWE:

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;

public class tests
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS) );
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS) );
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i ++)
            panel.add(new JLabel("Label") );
        
        JScrollPane scroll_pane = new JScrollPane(panel,
            ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
            ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        
        frame.add(scroll_pane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        
        System.out.println(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight() );
        System.out.println(frame.getHeight() );
    }
}
```

For me, the output is

```
1080.0
1100
```

How can I fix this?

EDIT:
I already tried `frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_VERT);`, however that doesn't change anything. `frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);` does work, but I do not want the window to span the whole width!

Comment: ok, and what is your actual question?

Comment: sorry ;-), just  added it

Comment: why don't you just set the size of the jframe?

Comment: I could, but for some reason, I have to set the height to 1087 instead of 1080 to fill the whole height. How does that number change with different screen sizes and resolutions? This solution doesn't seem very flexible...

Comment: you could try making it a bit 'smaller' and then programmatically maximizing it

Comment: wdym by 'programmatically maximizing'?

Comment: writing a line of code that 'maximizes' the screen. You know on the top right you can have those minimize/maximize options? perform that automatically at startup

Comment: frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); if you're lazy :)

Comment: doesn't work, see the edit